# Error trying to UPDATE php/mysql code for changing to a new password

Tags: php, html, mysql

As described in the title, I am running into an SQL injection error:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1`

How do I fix this?  Provided below is my php code and html code

PHP:

```
if($_POST['submit']=='Change')
{
    $err = array();
    if(!$_POST['password1'] || !$_POST['passwordnew1'])
        $err[] = 'All the fields must be filled in!';
    if(!count($err))
    {
        $_POST['password1'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password1']);
        $_POST['passwordnew1'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['passwordnew1']);
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT id,username FROM members WHERE username='{$_SESSION['username']}' AND pass='".md5($_POST['password1'])."'"));
        if($row['username'])
        {
            $querynewpass = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET pass='".md5($_POST['passwordnew1'])."' WHERE username='{$_SESSION['username']}'");
            $result = mysql_query($querynewpass) or die(mysql_error()); 
        }
        else $err[]='Wrong Password To Start With!';
    }
    if($err)
    $_SESSION['msg']['passwordchange-err'] = implode('<br />',$err);
    header("Location: members.php?id=" . $_SESSION['username']);
    exit;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post">      
<?php
        if($_SESSION['msg']['passwordchange-err'])
        {
        echo '<div class="err">'.$_SESSION['msg']['passwordchange-err'].'</div>';
        unset($_SESSION['msg']['passwordchange-err']);
        }
        if($_SESSION['msg']['passwordchange-success'])
        {
        echo '<div class="success">'.$_SESSION['msg']['passwordchange-success'].'</div>';
        unset($_SESSION['msg']['passwordchange-success']);
        }
?>
    <label class="grey" for="password1">Current Password:</label>
    <input class="field" type="password" name="password1" id="password1" value="" size="23" />
    <label class="grey" for="password">New Password:</label>
    <input class="field" type="password" name="passwordnew1" id="passwordnew1" size="23" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Change" class="bt_register" style="margin-left: 382px;" />
</form>
```

I have it working where a user is able to change/update their password, however, when they click the Change button on the form, they are directed to that error message I posted above, and if they click the refresh button, only then they are redirected back to their profile and the changes have been made.  So my main question at hand is, how do I get this to fully work without that mysql error message?  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `'{$_SESSION['username']}'` I have a hunch it's these quotes. Escape the string and try `'".$_SESSION['username']."'`

Comment: Try this WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'

Comment: I'll give that a shot, one sec and I'll let you know if it worked...

Comment: Stop using deprecated functions (mysql_*), use PDO or Mysqli properly and you won't have to waste time escaping everything.

Comment: A few notes: 1. There's no use of doing `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password1'])` if you're sending it to a `md5()`. 2. There's no use to preform `SELECT` queries by username AND password. 3. It's better to save the userID on the `SESSION` and use it for queries instead of using the username

Comment: @Thiha That unfortunately didn't work, same error message...

Comment: @Itay, so how would I make that work?

Comment: @Michael can you tell which command makes the error? The SELECT or the UPDATE?

Comment: I'm assuming its the UPDATE --> It's the only section where I have 'or die(mysql_error());'

Comment: `members.php` is the code you have posted above or is another page?

Comment: There's no `or die()` on the above code. Also you should print the `{$_SESSION['username']}` on die() so you'd see if it has the correct value

Comment: @Italy, the or die() is on the original post --> `$querynewpass = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET pass='".md5($_POST['passwordnew1'])."' WHERE username='{$_SESSION['username']}'");
            $result = mysql_query($querynewpass) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: Identify the problematic SQL-query and point it out.

Comment: and @invisal, yes that code is on the members.php page ;)

Comment: What is the content of `$_SESSION['username']`? It might be worth escaping the value with `mysql_real_escape_string()` if it can contain quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except for what Connor said, you have a serious problem here:

```
    if($row['username'])
    {
        $querynewpass = 
   mysql_query("UPDATE members SET pass='".md5($_POST['passwordnew1']).
               "' WHERE username='{$_SESSION['username']}'");
        $result = mysql_query($querynewpass) or die(mysql_error()); 
    }
```

The first inner line **already performs** the [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) and returns *a resource*, which is assigned to *$querynewpass*.

You're resending the result (*a resource*) to another query, as if it was *a string* containing the SQL command you want to perform.

This is the function's specification:

```
resource mysql_query ( string $query [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )
```

This is the correct usage of mysql_query (which is deprecated as people mentioned):

```
    if($row['username'])
    {
        $querynewpass = 
               "UPDATE members SET pass='".md5($_POST['passwordnew1']).
               "' WHERE username='{$_SESSION['username']}'";
        $result = mysql_query($querynewpass) or die(mysql_error()); 
    }
```

Comment: @Micahel Please understand the logic behind my fix and read carefully Connor Peet's excellent remarks below. It's vital to your development.

Comment: Thank you again and I will!  I do have another question, what exactly do you mean by deprecated?

Comment: @Michael We mean it's out dated, old fashioned, unsafe, not supported and was replaced with better libraries like [MySQLi](http://il1.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

Comment: @Italy, would you be able to help me out on this?  I posted another question, and have no idea how to get this to work, here is the link to my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18344533/how-to-allow-users-logged-in-to-update-edit-their-profile-settings-information

Answer (score 7):

A few things wrong here, more than can be put in a comment. I'm sorry, I can't see exactly what your error is, but if you follow point #1, it'll go away.

1. Don't use the `mysql` library. It is deprecated, and has been removed (finally!) in PHP 5.5. It is only working for you at the moment, because your version of PHP is out of date. You should either be using PDO or MySQLi. Check out this article for information on PDO: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly/
2. Don't put any variable that's not generated in the script you're looking at into your query, this includes SESSION variables. You just need one flaw in your application, and the user can inject data into the SESSION. Treat every variable as dirty. If you know that it isn't - 100% for certain - then treat it as dirty. If you use prepared statements with PDO or MySQLi, this isn't a problem.
3. You should reference users by their ID, not username. Much faster and safer.
4. Never ever ever ever store passwords raw or simply encrypted (like with plain `md5()`) in the database. At the very least, you can encrypt with something like: `crypt($password, '$2a$07$sillystring' . sha1($password) . '$')` and verify by recrpyting the password and see if it matches. That's a very basic, more secure way of doing it. There are many articles written on *password salting* that go more in depth and are worth checking out.

Comment: Thank you for this information Connor --> I'll look more into using PDO or MySQLi!  Again thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet could help to you

```
$pass1 = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password1']));
$newpass = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['passwordnew1']));
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username'])
$query = "SELECT id,username FROM members WHERE username = '$username' AND pass = '$pass1'";
$result = mysql_query($query); //that could also use , mysql_query($query,$yourconnection);
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    $updatequery = "UPDATE members SET pass='$newpass' WHERE username='$username'";
    $updateresult = mysql_query($updatequery) or die(mysql_error()); 
}
```

Please note that `mysql` library is deprecated in after php ver 5.5.0